# is there any way to know if Vimeo server is down while embeding a video on my site?

Tags: javascript, vimeo

I have a problem with some vimeo videos embeded on my site in an iframe. If vimeo server is down (or maybe becasue of a network problem) an ugly message appears on the screen. I would like to use a replacement img if there is a problem with the embeded video. 
Is there any way to do it (maybe through JS)?

Answer (score 0):

If your iframe has a class or ID, you can use the following to test for content.

Kinda Pseudo code (since I dont know what your code looks like)

```
<iframe class="foo"></iframe>
```

//check if iFrame contents are empty (or check for whatever displays in the iFrame when video does not load)

```
if(foo.contents().find("body").html()=="") {
    foo.append("<img src="/img/someimg.jpg" alt="someimg" style="width:200px; height:auto;")
}
```

You will have to edit this code to suit your situation, but at least it should demonstrate how to check iFrame content.